Google Voice2Text unable to transcribe audio files - totalBilledTime is unknown
I am trying to transcribe an ogg file (tried wav as well) and always receive an error:
Error occurred during parsing: Error occurred during parsing: totalBilledTime is unknown.
I am using PHP 8 with the latest lib "google/cloud": "^0.239.0"
Tried with some different ogg files (received from whatsapp)....they are small files usually with 15 kb.
    function getAudio2Text($RecordingUrl, &$text, &$error)
    {
        // Configura o ambiente com a chave da conta de serviço
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);

        $text = null;
        $error = null;

        // Configura o cliente da API
        $client = new SpeechClient();

        try {
            // Configuração da solicitação
            $config = (new RecognitionConfig())
                ->setEncoding(AudioEncoding::LINEAR16)
                ->setSampleRateHertz(44100)
                ->setLanguageCode('pt-BR'); // Ou o idioma que você precisa

            // Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
            $audioContent = file_get_contents($RecordingUrl);

            $audio = (new RecognitionAudio())
                ->setContent($audioContent);

            // Faz a solicitação e obtém a resposta
            $response = $client->recognize($config, $audio);

            // Processa a resposta
            foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
                $alternatives = $result->getAlternatives();
                $mostLikely = $alternatives[0];
                $text .= $mostLikely->getTranscript();
            }
            return array(
                'success' => true,
                'alternatives' => $alternatives,
                'mostLikely' => $mostLikely,
                'text' => $text
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
            return array(
                'success' => false,
                'error' => $error
            );
        } finally {
            $client->close();
        }

        if (empty($text)) {
            $error = "Não foi possível transcrever o áudio.";
        }
    }


the problem was with the version...i upgraded and it worked:
final versions:
{
"require": {
"php": "8.3.",
"google/cloud": "^0.243.0",
"google/apiclient": "^2.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4.5",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.283",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0",
"google/cloud-text-to-speech": "",
"twilio/sdk": "dev-main",
"sendgrid/sendgrid": "dev-main",
"stripe/stripe-php": "^13.10@beta"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
